# Validate mobile number using regular expression in android

Tags: android, regex, validation

How to validate mobile number using regular expression.
mobile number must starts with non zero number and contains only 10 digits

Comment: Thank you for the exercise, prof.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
System.out.println("1000000000".matches("^[1-9][0-9]{9}$"));
System.out.println("0000000030".matches("^[1-9][0-9]{9}$"));
System.out.println("000000003301".matches("^[1-9][0-9]{9}$"));

Output:
true
false
false
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would need an RE(If you really do, read almas's answer), you mentioned java and android, a simple method like this should do (Assuming you have the number as a string "num"):

```
private boolean validateNumber(String num) {
    if(num.length = 10 && !num[0].equals("0")){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```